# White space ascii characters removal

Tags: java

how to remove  white space ascii characters in the String using any apache lang or regular
expressions or any other library.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: Thanks,Here what is 's+' means

Comment: \s is for white space characters in Regex and the + is to match one or more occurrences of white space.

Comment: Thank you! After searching high and low, trying multiple ways to rid of some character encoding issues, this one finally solved it. Awesome work!